# conditional expected value and in Stochastic differential equations

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Let's suppose I have a bidimensional SDE of the form:

\begin{equation} \label{eq:system}
\begin{cases}
dX_t=b(t,X_t,Y_t)dt+\sigma(t,X_t,Y_t)dW_t^1 \\
X_0=x_0 \\
dY_t= B(t,X_t,Y_t)dt+C(t,X_t,Y_t)dW_t^2 \\
Y_0=y_0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where $W^1,W^2$ are Brownian motions.

Now take a time $s>0$, since $X_s,Y_s$ are random variables it should make sense to compute $\mathbb{E}[X_{s}|Y_s ]$.

My question are:

can I apply the tower property in this way?
$$\mathbb{E}[X_{s}|Y_s ]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X_{s}|(Y_\tau, \tau \leq s) ]|Y_s ]$$

What does it mean to compute $\mathbb{E}[X_{s}|Y_s ]$ when the process $X_s$ depends (by the sde) on the all history of $Y_\tau, \tau \leq s$?